# Test iPhone in-app purchases on a different bundle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, in-app-purchase

We have a group of beta testers for iPhone app. Recently, we added in-app purchases to the app.

Before this, we would send out ad hoc builds to beta testers using a separate bundle ID and name so that they could have the store build and the ad hoc build on their phones.

However, it seems like we have to build the ad hoc copy with the same Bundle ID to test in-app purchases, and this means we can't send out a seperate beta copy - our beta file (annoyingly) overwrites the user's store-bought app.

Is there any way to test in-app purchases in a different bundle ID? Do I need to set up fake, test in-app purchases for the test build too?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty certain you do-upload to ITC and then reject the binary.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change the binary's product name it will install as two separate apps, but I'm not certain on this.
So you itunes one will be `foo` and your dev one could be `foobeta`